# Google Kubernetes Engine Spring Boot App Cant Connect To Database Within Same Network

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a spring boot app deployed to GKE in the us-central1 region. There is a postgres database that runs on a compute engine VM instance. Both are a part of the 'default' VPC network. I can ping this database by its hostname from within one of the GKE pods. However when the spring boot app launches and attempts connection to the database using the same hostname like so in the properties file, I get a connection timeout error and the app fails to startup:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://database01:5432/primary`

We have similar connections to this database from other VM instances that work fine. There is aalso a similar setup with Kafka and the app is also unable to resolve the broker hostnames. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to access MySQL manually (by running mysql command) from the VM instance where the spring boot app is deployed? It would be easier to check why it fails.

Comment: If you deploy PostgreSQL to "compute engine VM instance" outside your kubernetes cluster, this will not work. You need to expose your database with external dns name (see my answer). Unfortunately, I don't know how exactly it should be done on GKE. I suggest either deploy PostgreSQL to Kubernetes Cluster or create PostgreSQL as external service in GKE.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is installed as external database on GKE, then you need to create "ExternalName" service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgresql
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: usermgmtdb.csw6ylddqss8.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

In this case, you need to know the "externalName" of your external PostgreSQL service, which is external dns name.

Otherwise, if you deploy PostgreSQL to your Kubernetes Cluster, you need to create PersistentVolumeClaim, StorageClass, PostgreSQL Deployment and PostgreSQL ClusterIP service.

See the manifest examples here: https://github.com/stacksimplify/aws-eks-kubernetes-masterclass/tree/master/04-EKS-Storage-with-EBS-ElasticBlockStore/04-03-UserManagement-MicroService-with-MySQLDB/kube-manifests